# axios post request fails with bad request

Tags: axios

I try to do a simple post request with axios.

My code snippet:

```
const getOauthToken = async () => {
  try {

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-ProxyPass' : '...',
    }


    const data = {
        ...
    }

    return await axios.post('/oauth2/token', data, {headers: headers});
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to get an authentication token. Reason ${error}`);
  }

};
```

This call fails with http 400. When I set the headers as default with

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['X-ProxyPass'] = '...';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the documentation of axios. 
If I use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", I have to use querystring to serialize in the needed format.

```
return await axios.post('/oauth2/token', querystring.stringify(data), {headers: headers});
```

But why it works, when I set the headers as default headers i still mysterious.